# Redirect to page Contact Phone IOS in cordova-Codenameone

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, codenameone

I use **Cordova Hybrid Apps in Codename One**
and My question is : "How can I call, from AngularJS, the contacts page of my IPhone".

Thanks

Comment: pls refer this link http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/

Answer (score 1):

For access to device APIs when using a Codename One /Cordova hybrid app, you'll need to use the [Javascript bridge](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html) to provide access to the Codename One [Contacts API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/contacts/package-summary.html).

See the section on "Calling Java Methods from Javascript" on [this page](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html) for an example of how to expose Java APIs to javascript.